# Disabling the stack smashing protection and Non-executable stack in Android.mk file

Tags: android, makefile, stack-overflow

I've written a simple android application using jni to support my native class. I need to change the Android.mk file in order to **disable** the **stack smashing protection** and **Non-executable stack**.I know that I should use switches like `-fno-stack-protector` and `-z execstack` with gcc. But how can I configure Android.mk to enforce the compiler to use these switches and flags?
I'm new in android programming and I would appreciate it if anyone could help me with this.

Thank you in advance,

The content of my Android.mk is as follows:

```
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)
include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_MODULE := com_farzane_armvuln_ARMvulnerable
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := armvul.c
include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)
```

Answer (score 0):

`LOCAL_CFLAGS+=...` will do the trick.